# How can I split a javascript array and replace elements of it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, split

*updated* 
I'm quite a new to this. I have looked everywhere and tried everything under the sun to fix this on my own. 
My data is from a text input where i need to read specific line. My code reads the lines perfectly using the slice(2,1) method. Now I need to use the data to do other things.

my extracted string from reading data lines from 3rd line data till 2nd last line, and this already works:

var x = readData.slice(2,-1).toString();

Output using console.log(x); *//0 1,2 3,4 5 as it should be*

but I want: '0,1','2,3','4,5'

So that i can use this data to do other things.

I have tried:

var x = readData.slice(2,-1).toString().split(' ',-1);

this gives me: [ '0', '1,2', '3,4', '5' ] //which is the closest

i have also tried:

var x = readData.slice(2,-1).toString().replace(/\s/g, ', ').split(" ", -1); which gives [ '0,', '1,2,', '3,4,', '5' ]

var x = [x.split(' ').join(',')]; which gives [ '0,1,2,3,4,5' ]

and a few other combos too. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you post the input structure in valid Javascript syntax, so we can be sure of exactly what you have, along with the desired output structure in JS syntax?

Comment: Is this `0 1,2 3,4 5` a string? or an array as follow `["0 1","2 3","4 5"]`

Answer (score -1):

According to the following statement

```
.replace(/\s/g, ', ').split(" ", -1); which gives [ '0,', '1,2,', '3,4,', '5' ]
```

in the question, this `0 1,2 3,4 5` is a string, so you can split by comma and then map the strings according to the desired output

```js
console.log("0 1,2 3,4 5".split(",").map(s => s.split(/\s+/g).join(",")));
```